# Convert to CSV value to Clojure list

Tags: clojure

What is the best way to turn this line of CSV for column 3 to a Clojure list?

```
357302041352401, 2012-08-27 19:59:32 -0700, 100, ["SNIA34", "M33KLC", "M34KLC", "W35REK", "SRBT", "MODE", "BFF21S", "CC12", "RCV56V", "NBA1", "RESP", "A0NTC", "PRNK", "WAYS", "HIRE", "BITE", "INGA1", "M32MOR", "TFT99W", "TBF5P", "NA3NR"]
```

Comment: What is the data before the vector? Is that data part of your .csv file?

Comment: Yes, that is one line from a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can already read the csv file...

You can use [read-string](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/read-string) in combination with [into](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/into)

```
user=> (def your_csv_column "[\"SNIA34\", \"M33KLC\", \"M34KLC\"]")
#'user/your_csv_column
user=> (into '() (read-string your_csv_column))
("M34KLC" "M33KLC" "SNIA34")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Clojure Csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv/) to do that.

Comment: In the readme on the github page (the link), there's an example of pulling the csv out. The simplest thing to do would be to read the line as a string, replace the left and right brackets with and empty string then use the csv api to just pull the entire thing in.

Answer (score 1):

You data is interesting, which appears to include a traditional comma-separated line, followed by data in brackets. I could not quite tell if the bracketed data was the representation you had in the .csv file or wanted after reading, but either way, this is how I read a .csv file:

My library's project.clj that uses clojure-csv:

```
(defproject util "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A general purposes Clojure library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]]
  :aot [util.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

My library's core.clj header:

```
(ns util.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "util is a Clojure utilities directory containing things
          most Clojure programs need, like cli routines.
        Created on April 4, 2012"}

  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:import java.io.File)
  (:use clojure-csv.core))
```

My library's function that returns a .csv file parsed as a vector of vectors.

```
(defn ret-csv-data
"Returns a lazy sequence generated by parse-csv.
 Uses open-file which will return a nil, if
 there is an exception in opening fnam.

 parse-csv called on non-nil file, and that
 data is returned."

 [fnam]
 (let [  csv-file (open-file fnam)

   inter-csv-data (if-not (nil? csv-file)
                    (parse-csv csv-file)
                     nil)

  csv-data (vec (filter #(and pos? (count %) (not (nil? (rest %)))) 
            inter-csv-data))]

    ;removes blank sequence at EOF.                
    (pop csv-data)))

(defn fetch-csv-data
    "This function accepts a csv file name, and returns parsed csv data,
     or returns nil if file is not present."

    [csv-file]
        (let [csv-data (ret-csv-data csv-file)]
            csv-data))
```

What I have found to be very helpful is avoid using nth -- very useful advice from SO and other sources -- and given most of my .csv data is from database queries, I zipmap columns to each .csv seqeuence (row), and then operate on that data by map key. It simplifies things for me.